# Batch FOR loop output showing whole command instead of just output when using PIPE

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, pipe

I'm attempting to send command output to a remote host using an SSH session established via Plink.  My current command looks like the following (the infinite loop is intentional:

```
(for /l in %n (1,0,2) do ping 1.1.1.1 -n -w 1000 >nul & echo %RANDOM%) | plink.exe sessionName -l %user "cat > outputfile.txt"
```

I would expect outputfile.txt to contain a randomly generated number, but instead it contains this:

```
C:\(PATH)> ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 1>nul & echo 9001
```

Why is the whole command being sent over, rather than just the random number?

As an aside, it's also appending to the remote file instead of rewriting.  The remote host is Linux based, so I would expect it to rewrite the file since I'm using > and not >>.

Comment: 1. A pipe creates a `cmd.exe` instance for either side, where `for` echoes its body code; to avoid that, precede each command with `@`, or enclose the entire body within `()` and put a `@` before the opening parenthesis. 2. The `in` keyword is missing in the `for /l` command line. 3. The `for /l` loop defines an infinite loop, unless you change the step value to `1`, like `in (1,1,2)`. 4. In the `plink` part there are unbalanced quotation marks. 5. I guess the returned random number is the same for every iteration, unless you force [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: The @ before the parens didn't help, but putting one in front of ping and echo solved the problem.  Thanks!

The missing in was a typo here, but it's included in my actual code.  Thanks for pointing that out.

The loop is supposed to be infinite, which I should probably state next.  I'll be sure to edit the post.

Plink quotes was another typo in here, but not the code.

Good link on delayed expansion.  I hadn't seen that before.  

Thanks again.  That answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A pipe creates a `cmd.exe` instance for either side, where `for` echoes its body code for every iteration. To avoid that, precede each command with `@`, or enclose the entire body within `()` and put a `@` before the opening parenthesis, like this...:

   ```
   for /L %n in (1,0,2) do @ping 1.1.1.1 -n -w 1000 >nul & @echo %RANDOM%
   ```

   ...or this, respectively:

   ```
   for /L %n in (1,0,2) do @(ping 1.1.1.1 -n -w 1000 >nul & echo %RANDOM%)
   ```
2. The `in` keyword is missing in the `for /L` command line, it must read:

   ```
   for /L %n in (1,0,2) do
   ```
3. The `for /L` loop defines an infinite loop (I am not sure if you intend that), unless you change the step value to `1`, like:

   ```
   for /L %n in (1,1,2) do
   ```
4. To use the code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) (according to the tags), you need to double the `%` sign, like:

   ```
   for /L %%n in (1,1,2) do
   ```
5. In the `plink` part there are unbalanced precent signs and quotation marks. For the remaining part herein, I assume it should read (since I do not know that tool):

   ```
   plink -l %user%
   ```
6. The returned random number is going to be the same for every loop iteration, because variable `%RANDOM%` is expanded to (replaced by) a random number once the entire command line is parsed, unless you force [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

   ```
   cmd /V /C "for /l %%n in (1,1,2) do @(ping 1.1.1.1 -n -w 1000 >nul & echo !RANDOM!)" | plink -l %user% > "outputfile.txt"
   ```